# MongoDB find() with specific conditions

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose I have two person, they both won the National Medal of Science and other awards. I want to find out which person won the National Medal of Science award after 1980. So I tried

```
db.scientists.find({$and: [
        {
            "awards.award": "National Medal of Science"
        },
        {
            "awards.year": {$gt: 1980
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

and the it return both of the scientists' name. I guess my question would be how do I apply a condition to a condition in MongoDB. Sorry for my poor English. Thanks.

```
"name" : {
    "first" : "John", 
    "last" : "Backus"
}, 

"awards" : [
    {
        "award" : "W.W. McDowell Award", 
        "year" : 1967.0, 
        "by" : "IEEE Computer Society"
    }, 
    {
        "award" : "National Medal of Science", 
        "year" : 1975.0, 
        "by" : "National Science Foundation"
    }, 
    {
        "award" : "Turing Award", 
        "year" : 1977.0, 
        "by" : "ACM"
    }, 
    {
        "award" : "Draper Prize", 
        "year" : 1993.0, 
        "by" : "National Academy of Engineering"
    }
]




"name" : {
    "first" : "John", 
    "last" : "McCarthy"
}, 

"awards" : [
    {
        "award" : "Turing Award", 
        "year" : 1971.0, 
        "by" : "ACM"
    }, 
    {
        "award" : "Kyoto Prize", 
        "year" : 1988.0, 
        "by" : "Inamori Foundation"
    }, 
    {
        "award" : "National Medal of Science", 
        "year" : 1990.0, 
        "by" : "National Science Foundation"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#query-an-array-of-documents);

```
db.scientists.find({
    awards: {
        $elemMatch: {
            award: "National Medal of Science",
            year: { $gt: 1980 }
        }
    }
});
```

should do the trick

#### Breif explanation

MongoDB searches arrays by a whole, so it gives you the result of;

any array that contains;

- an element with 'award': "National Medal of Science"
- an element with 'year': { $gt: 1980 }

`$elemMatch` solves this by forcing element based match. <sub>not so intuitive</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, that answered my question.

Comment: @lishen If it helped, may you select this as accepted answer(tick on the left)

Answer (score 0):

Often JSON documents are nested inside each other. This means that a key refers to another key value hash. In this case too, MongoDB offers the possibility to search for documents based on values ​​stored in a nested JSON structure:

```
{ 
  "_id": ObjectId ("568c28fffc4be30d44d039aa"), 
  "firstname": "Max", 
  "lastname": "Mustermann", 
  "email": "m.mustermann@example.com", 
  "password": "d9729feb74992cc3482b350163a1a010, 
  " last_login ":" 2015-01-07 ", 
  " note ":" Always pays in time, very good customer! ", 
  " address ": 
  { 
    " country ":" Germany ", 
    " street ":" Beispielstrasse 64 ", 
    " zip ":" 62717 " 
  } 
}
```